# Struts 2: Unable to load configuration. - action

Tags: struts2, jasper-reports

I am trying to use JasperReport with Struts2.

As soon as I put:

```
<result name="pdfA" type="jasper">
    <param name="location">/WEB-INF/itemplates/template-A.jasper</param>
    <param name="dataSource">templateMap</param>
    <param name="format">PDF</param>
</result>
```

The Tomcat7 gives an exception:

> Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/C:/JAVA/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/project/WEB-INF/classes/order.xml:28:105
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:446)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:490)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.listener.StrutsListener.contextInitialized(StrutsListener.java:46)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   Caused by: Error building results for action courtorderprint in namespace /order - action - file:/C:/JAVA/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/project/WEB-INF/classes/order.xml:28:105
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:437)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:552)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:292)
>       at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:250)
>       at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)

I checked the lib, seems everything is there.
...but it is still gives me an exception.

WEB.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_9" version="2.4">
<display-name>project</display-name>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.listener.StrutsListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>tilesDefinitions</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: `web.xml` required to post.

Comment: So what is line 28 in `order.xml`?

Comment: again, as soon as I remove <results type="jasper".... --everything is working. 

Definitely it is not web.xml
... and line#28: <result name="pdfA" type="jasper">
For a certain reason it doesn't recognized: type="jasper"

Comment: Have you added jasper plugin jar into classpath? Have you defined jasper result in your configuration? Post the whole configuration.

Comment: And the entire stack trace, making sure you're in devMode and at debug log level.